# Ubuntu 16.04 default Chrome launcher

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04 and selected it as my default browser then restarted the computer. But I am still seeing Firefox in the Launcher and not chrome.

How can I change this, please?

Comment: Launch _chrome_ then __right click__on it and select __lock to __launcher__ and it should stick.

Answer (score 1):

The process is:

1. Launch *chrome*
2. Right click on it in the launcher and **select lock to launcher**

[image]

And you should see *chrome* still there after you closed it.